# How to make a conditional function call using setState callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-state

The below function logic works, but reading through various posts and SO questions, learned that this should be avoided. So, I'm trying to use callback in setState to reference the previous state. saveOptions function call is dependent on the state change.

**Converted the below code**

```
validateOnSave() {
    const copy = this.state.codeSelectionIsInvalid;
    copy[0] = !this.state.reasonCode;
    copy[1] = !this.state.remarkCode;
    copy[2] = !this.state.otherCode;
    this.setState({ codeSelectionIsInvalid: copy });

   if (!copy[0] && !copy[1] && !copy[2]) {
      this.saveOptions();
    }
  }
```

**To use callback**

```
validateOnSave() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      codeSelectionIsInvalid: [!prevState.reasonCode, !prevState.remarkCode, !prevState.otherCode],
      },
      () => {
        if(!prevState.reasonCode && !prevState.remarkCode && !prevState.otherCode) {
          this.saveOptions();
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Error:

```
{ SyntaxError: OptionsView.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (110:2)

  108 |       }
  109 |     )
> 110 |   }
```

But this is not quite working. Giving me syntax errors. Where am I going wrong here?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: Added the error message.

Comment: try `this.setState(prevState => {return {.....}},()=>{.....})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first callback, you are forgetting the close `)` to complete the shorthand arrow function i.e.

```
prevState => ({
  codeSelectionIsInvalid: [!prevState.reasonCode, !prevState.remarkCode, !prevState.otherCode],
}), // <-- closing bracket
() => { ...
```

Comment: If I put the closing bracket there, I'm not able to use prevState in the callback function. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Vidhi is it really the previous state you are after or is it the updated state? If so, you can simply use `this.state`